# Does Tomcat server use TCP or UDP?

Tags: tomcat

I have to open some ports in my firewall to let users access Tomcat through the network. I have to specify the port type. Does tomcat use TCP or UDP?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since you're (apparently) using Tomcat as an HTTP server, it's probably safe to assume that you want TCP.

From the [Tomcat docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-4.1-doc/config/coyote.html):

> The Coyote HTTP/1.1 Connector element represents a Connector component that supports the HTTP/1.1 protocol. It enables Catalina to function as a stand-alone web server, in addition to its ability to execute servlets and JSP pages. A particular instance of this component **listens for connections on a specific TCP port number** on the server.

Comment: Yes, I am using Tomcat as an HTTP server. Thanks

Comment: @RafaelSanchezGuayasamin Please feel free to upvote/accept if this answers your question.